# Initialize y-axis to be centered at 0

Tags: plot, bokeh

I'm generating some line plots that show percent error results. It would be nice if the y-axis was centered at 0 when the plots first load. I know I can manually set the bounds for the y-axis, but it would be tedious to have to set them manually for each figure.

Is there a way to set the figures to center at 0 along the y-axis?

Here's some code that may provide additional details -

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.io import gridplot, hplot

# prepare some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [-10, -9, 23, 4, -6]
y2 = [-15, -4, 26, 32, -45]
y3 = [-42, -20, -13, -34, -59]
y4 = [-23, -34, -32, -43, -53]

# output to static HTML file
output_file("lines.html", title="line plot example")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p.line(x, y1, line_width=2)
p.line(x, y2, line_width=2)

p2 = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p2.line(x, y3, line_width=2)
p2.line(x, y4, line_width=2)

p = hplot(p, p2)
show(p)
```

This generates two plots. The one on the right shows the problem I'm running into. Since all of the values are negative, the y-axis bounds are narrowed to approximately -10 to -60. I would like that chart to be bound at -60 to 60, so that it's aligned at 0.

Update: 
I ended up just defining a function that will return the absolute max of the y values. Then, I am doing the following to set the limits:

```
axisLimit = getAxisRange(list1, list2) #get absolute max from the two lists
p.y_range = Range1d(start=-1*axisLimit, end=axisLimit)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no Bokeh method to center a plot around an axis like you describe. What did you did in your update seems like a good solution. You're always welcome to open an issue on the Bokeh project tracker at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues